# How to pivot table results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in the following format:

```
-----------------------
| Red | Blue | Yellow |
-----------------------
| 23  | 34   | 343    |
-----------------------
```

I trying to find a way using which I can select result in following format:

```
------------------
| Type   | Count | 
------------------
| Red    | 23    |
| Blue   | 34    |
| Yellow | 343   |
------------------
```

I am using a condition so that there will always be one row in result.

Can you please tell me any way using which I can achieve this?

I tried google, found pivot option but it requires aggregate function and I don't know how it will apply to my problem.

Comment: did you just try to google your problem?
https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot#pivot

Answer (score 2):

You need an `UNPIVOT` operation:

```
with yourTable(Red, Blue, Yellow) as (
    select 23, 34, 343 from dual
)    
select *
from yourTable
unpivot ( count for Type in (Red as 'Red', Blue as 'Blue', Yellow as 'Yellow'))
```

[Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) you fine some useful examples of `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use union

```
select 'Red' type, Red
from my_table 
union 
select 'Blue' type, Blue
from my_table 
union 
select 'Yellow' type, Yellow
from my_table
```